# changing title for BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, title, uibarbuttonitem

I created redirection from local notification to questionViewController (in appDelegate.m):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 cysViewController *cvc =[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cysViewController"];
 questionViewController *qvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"questionViewController"];
 qvc.categoryId = @"339";
 UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
 nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cvc,qvc, nil];
 [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController popToViewController:qvc animated:YES];
 // back button appearance
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(107/255.0) green:  (11/255.0) blue:(47/255.0) alpha:1]];
}
```

Everything works fine. Back item is shown and his appearance is changed. I would like to change title of back button, but I have no idea how to do that. I tried some examples but without success. Does anyone have an idea to change title of back button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cvc.navigationItem.title = @"Some Title";
```

Comment: Or `cvc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Some Title";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  @"my title";
```

Comment: tried this but got an error: property navigationitem not fund on object of type appDelegate

Comment: add this in the viewWillAppear of your view

Comment: added, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
     self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Title";
}
```

Comment: did you try this, self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
           target:nil
           action:nil];

Comment: this works fine for label text, but not for title of bar button item

Comment: yes, tried this, but no result. QuestionViewController is not a navigation Controller, propably this is a reason why it not works